# Why do delegate methods work without declaring protocol conformance?

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextfield, objective-c-protocol

I have one `UITextField`, and I drag from it to its owner to set the `delegate` in storyboard.

And in my controller.h file, I didn't declare the class as conforming to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

But the `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` works! It just works!

And I wonder why?

I have met this once before when I set UITableView to a controller which does not have `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: it happens, when you give connection between file's owner and connection tools. so delegate method will start work

Comment: check in your xib file. may be the delegate connected to the file's owner

Comment: OP is not asking about setting `textField.delegate = self`. He is asking why the delegation works without declaring the **conformance** to the `UITextFieldDelegate` **protocol.** It's just that he uses wrong terminology.

Comment: @H2CO3 , yeah, that's what I am asking. Could you edit the question to remove the wrong terminology? My English is poor

Comment: @PuttinWong Well, that's because the objects don't check for protocol conformance, they check if the delegate responds to a selector. In other words, the protocol is only for fooling the compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3 , thanks! And I agree with you. Why not create an answer so that I can accept that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods are invoked because the delegating objects (`UIWebView`, `UITextField`, `UITableView`, etc.) don't check if the delegate conforms to a protocol. They are only interested in if it **actually** responds to a certain delegate method.

Protocol declarations, after all, are just hints for the compiler.